# Emacs 24.5 install auto-complete error

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I want to install auto-complete in Emacs, but there are always warnings.

I use auto-complete on GitHub.

I use the default config, but wrong:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugin/auto-complete")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

I tried:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-as-directory
             (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/plugin/auto-complete")))
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

but it doesn't work.

Windows 8.1 Emacs 24.5

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: FWIW, nowadays most people seem to prefer `company` over `auto-complete`.  You can install it from `M-x list-packages RET`.

Comment: @Stefan's comment is irrelevant to the question asked (granted, he did add "FWIW"). And you can also install `auto-complete.el` from `M-x list-packages`. "Nowadays"..."most"..."seem to prefer"...

Comment: See @Chris's question. What exactly does "*but it doesn't work*" mean? If you want better help then try to provide more/better information about the problem/question.

Comment: @Drew: admittedly, it's not strictly speaking directly relevant.  The reason I mention it is that auto-complete used to be the "most common" package to provide this kind of feature and that sometimes people don't necessarily want "the auto-complete package" but really "some package that does something they've heard called «auto-completion»".  If the OP really wants specifically the `auto-complete` package, then indeed my remark is beside the point.

Comment: thanks you help.I fix it .first I post the pictrue when I edit done.it tell me I cant sorry for you time.and thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All. I already fix it.

> Beacuse I lost popup.el .

If some one what install this auto-complete not by pakeages.

You shoule install popup.el first.
I do it like this:

1. 1.go to github https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el
2. use M+x RET load-file to install auto-complete and input Directory for it(like ~/.emcas.d/plugins/auto-complete)
3. Copy the popup.el into where you (require 'auto-complete-config) File Directory keep it on the same Directory.

Comment: I first use stack thanks you help and how i can close this question.